# jquery click each

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть 2 группы радио кнопок

```
    <div class="gruppa_1">

<input id="gruppa_1_1" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="11" type="radio">
<input id="gruppa_1_2" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="12" type="radio">
<input id="gruppa_1_3" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="13" type="radio">
            </div>
    <div class="gruppa_2">

<input id="gruppa_2_1" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="21" type="radio">
<input id="gruppa_3_2" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="22" type="radio">
<input id="gruppa_4_3" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="33" type="radio">
            </div>
```

Написал код

```
    jQuery('.gruppa_2  input:radio[name=gruppa_2]').on(function (e) {
    jQuery('.gruppa_1 input:radio[name=gruppa_1]').each(function (e) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
            jQuery($this).prop("checked", false);
        }
        console.log($this.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

Клик отрабатывает а снятие всех радио боксов не срабатывает но если запросить данную функцию ВНЕ клика то срабатывает. (НАПРИМЕР В КОНСОЛИ БРАУЗЕРА).

Вопрос как снять все флажки с первой группы если выбран флажок во 2 группе.

Comment: Что-то у меня очень большие подозрения, что ваш JS-код вообще работает.

Comment: И смущает фраза "снять все флажки с первой группы", потому что у группы радиобаттонов не может быть больше одного элемента с параметром `checked`.

Comment: @MasterAlex тут имеется ввиду состояние, когда ни один из флагов вообще не установлен: `jQuery($this).prop("checked", false)`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7bvfm899/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы откроете документацию, то [функция on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) принимает два обязательных параметра `events` и `handler`. У Вас в коде я вижу только один, следовательно код уже нерабочий.

Добавьте название обработчика "click" к функции и все заработает:

```js
jQuery('.gruppa_2  input:radio[name=gruppa_2]').on("click",function (e) {
    jQuery('.gruppa_1 input:radio[name=gruppa_1]').each(function (e) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if (jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {
            jQuery($this).prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gruppa_1">
    <input id="gruppa_1_1" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="11" type="radio">
    <input id="gruppa_1_2" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="12" type="radio">
    <input id="gruppa_1_3" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="13" type="radio">
</div>
<div class="gruppa_2">
    <input id="gruppa_2_1" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="21" type="radio">
    <input id="gruppa_3_2" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="22" type="radio">
    <input id="gruppa_4_3" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="33" type="radio">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Чтобы все пункты первого ряда можно было выделять, нужно сделать чтобы они были чекбоксами.
2) А чтобы убирать выделение у всех сразу пунктов `each` не обязательно.

В итоге вот так всё работает:

```js
jQuery('.gruppa_2  input[name=gruppa_2]').on("click", function(e) {
  jQuery('.gruppa_1 input[name=gruppa_1]').prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gruppa_1">

  <input id="gruppa_1_1" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="11" type="checkbox">
  <input id="gruppa_1_2" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="12" type="checkbox">
  <input id="gruppa_1_3" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_1" value="13" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="gruppa_2">

  <input id="gruppa_2_1" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="21" type="radio">
  <input id="gruppa_3_2" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="22" type="radio">
  <input id="gruppa_4_3" class="radioBtnClass" name="gruppa_2" value="33" type="radio">
</div>
```